# Swift returns "Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSArray' to type 'NSManagedObject'"

Tags: ios, swift

How possible I can convert NSArray to NSManagedObject? I want to delete object that contain `nurdin` in `uname` field.

```
        let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        let credContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Creds")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uname = %@", "nurdin")
        var result: NSArray = credContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        /* error here*/                
        credContext.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
```

My problem is I can't delete the object because of this issue

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSArray' to type 'NSManagedObject'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [the reference library documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:), executeFetchRequests returns an optional list of AnyObjects: `[AnyObject]?`

```swift
func executeFetchRequest(_ request: NSFetchRequest,
                       error error: NSErrorPointer) -> [AnyObject]?
```

You have to first unwrap it and then delete each object one by one:

```swift
var error: NSError?
if let objects = credContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject] {
    for obj in objects {
       credContext.deleteObject(obj)
    }
} else {
   // TODO: Error handling here
   println("Couldn't fetch objects \(error)")
}
```